# Is there a realtime apache/php console similar to webrick or mongrel with ruby on rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, apache, mongrel, webrick

Is there a realtime apache/php console similar to webrick or mongrel with ruby on rails?

I want to be able to monitor what the heck my server is doing.

### edit:

but I don't want to grep the log

Thanks!

Comment: What information are you looking for that

    tail -f /path/to/access.log

doesn't provide you with?

Comment: probably the same, but in an automatic way. would i have to periodically have to run tail manually? with RoR/webrick/mongrel you get realtime feedback as events occur. I'm running a long php script and I don't want to wait for it to finish to see what it's up to and I dont want to re-run tail myself

Comment: hm... it's not exactly real time. it waits for a script to finish running which leaves me where i started. it's cool to know though, thx. im looking for something i can use to follow outgoing connections not just incoming ones. also in RoR you can "puts <string>" to print to the console immediately.

Comment: i mean tail -f appears to be real time, but apache isn't writing to the log until it's done with whatever it's doing. i want to see the intermediate steps

Comment: most importantly, i want the outgoing connections that happen in order to build the page that the incoming connection asked for

Comment: Do write to stderr and flush, it will be real time then.

Comment: Or find where the buffer size is defined, and lower it, be aware there is a cost for that. I am not sure you can control the buffer size for the different output streams separately.

Comment: hmm.... i will look into your suggestions. thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I believe [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) might be somewhat equivalent to what your looking for.

**Simple Example:**

```
 <?php
 FB::log('Log message');
 FB::info('Info message');
 FB::warn('Warn message');
 FB::error('Error message');
 ?>
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [firephp.org](http://www.firephp.org/images/Screenshots/SimpleConsole.png))</sub>

[Read More](http://www.firephp.org/HQ/Use.htm)

Comment: Will have the same problem as with tail -f, Unless you flush after each FB:: call (which then can be disastrous for your headers)+add the time between request and  response.

Answer (score 0):

There's always gdb and strace/dtrace. There's also the xdebug module but its not real time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command in your application directory:

```
mongrel_rails start -B
```

This starts it in debug mode and gives you all the requests just like Webrick. Yes, including all those 'puts' statements.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really simple way: instead of monitoring the access.log apache2 file or the mongrel one, you can simple tail the production.log file and you will get the exact same behavior of webrick. So a solution is:

```
tail -f /your/project/path/log/production.log
```

Answer (score -1):

[ApacheTop](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/monitor-your-website-in-real-time-with-apachetop/) may not *quite* do what you want, but just in case.. and you might find it useful nonetheless :) It's basically like UNIX top but for Apache.